# Python timer 'NoneType' object is not callable error

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to make a program which is checks the given url for every 10 seconds

```
def listener(url):
    print ("Status: Listening")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()
    text = data.decode('utf-8')
    if text == 'Hello World. Testing!':
        print("--Action Started!--")


t = Timer(10.0,listener('http://test.com/test.txt'))
t.start()
```

here is the output:

```
Status: Listening
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1186, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It runs the function for one time, after 10 seconds the error appears

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, the result of your `listener` function call is being given to `Timer`, which is resultantly `None`, as you need to make an explicit return so your `Timer` has something to operate on.

You have to place the argument for your `listener()` in another parameter, like this. Note that `args` must be a sequence, thus the tuple with the comma placed after your `url`. Without this tuple, you are passing each individual character from `'http://test.com/test.txt'` as an argument to `listener`.

```
t = Timer(10.0,listener,args=('http://test.com/test.txt',))
```

As you can see in documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects), arguments must be passed as a third parameter.

Comment: What does the return type of the listener() have to be? I set the return as a string and got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Also, for some reason t = Timer(30.0, self.killDBConnection()) is not working as expected for me. I want to run the  self.killDBConnection() only after 30 seconds, but it get run immediately instead of after 30 seconds

Comment: This saved me, had a timer inside a supprocess.Popen() call and if it does not work it will not signal anything, moved it out and I saw the error from threading.Timer: `noneType not callable`. After I got it working on the outside, I could put it back again.